# Cannot connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql

I created a php file to connect to my database hosted on ipages.com with the following simple code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
?>
```

When I load this page, I get in return `0`. No error message. I previously could not connect to the website using FTP with Filezilla, I had to contact the host to give me access. Is there a similar problem here? I have to access the host to get access to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should look to switch to mysqli as the method you are using is being discouraged. The method you should be using is documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

The connection will simply create a connection object to your DB, beyond this it does nothing. You should look at using a block like the one below, which will give you an idea of the status of your connection object:

`$link = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
  if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);`

Comment: Its working now! thank you, but still how where I supposed to know that this method was old?

Comment: The Php.net manual page has it up top in red ;)